# coredate mul_condition filter

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have use codedate, I want to use `NSPredicate` to filter the result. I have a entity, there are three field: from and to. For example:

> from           to      info
>
> aa             bb      11111
>
> aa             cc      y6767
>
> bb             aa       4545
>
> bb             dd       3434

So I want to get `from=aa and to=bb` or `from =bb and to=aa`, so the result is:

> from         to      info
>
> aa           bb      11111
>
> bb           aa      4545
>
> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(from ==
>   %@) AND (to > %@) OR (from == %@) and (to == %@)",from, to,to ,from];
>
> or NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(from
>   == %@) AND (to > %@) OR ((from == %@) and (to == %@))",from, to,to ,from];

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: i  edit it,can you give  me help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(from == %@ AND to == %@) OR (from == %@ AND to == %@)",
        from, to, to, from]
```